# splitting date and inserting individual field in separate column in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have created a date table directly through phpmyadmin and i want to split the date(yyyy:mm:dd) into individual day, month and year and insert into separate field. Can anybody help me in the query used directly in phpmyadmin to perform above work?

Comment: We have `DAY()`, `MONTH()`, & `YEAR()` functions for that... But do yourself and every one on your project(s) a favor: just use a `DATE` column.....

Comment: Why? You can access each date element using MySQL `YEAR()`, `MONTH()`, `DAY()`. It's also a LOT faster doing this in SQL than pulling it out and parsing using another language...

Comment: You want to create separate fields for year, month, day by a query? Or you want add a date you have into separate fields? You can use a high level language(php, python, ruby, etc) in order to split a date and put it into separate fields in the db table. But for former one, you can use phpmyadmin gui ;)

Comment: Definitely put it all in a single column; this will not only reduce the number of columns you have to deal with, but you can take advantage of SQL ordering and other operations involving dates in your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `year` = YEAR(`date`), `month` = DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%m'), `day` = DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d')
```

I've used `DATE_FORMAT()` rather than `MONTH()` and `DAY()` as the latter two remove leading zeros.

Comment: i m sorry the querry was successful but no result is seen.....i mean the day. month and the year fields are all 0

Comment: Just to be sure; you're using back-ticks (or nothing) to escape the `date` field name, not single-quotes?

Comment: i am using single quotes. Will there be problem if the date field was declared as int rather than datetime

Comment: You don't use single-quotes to escape field names. You use back-ticks.

And if the `date` field has been declared as `int` then how is the data stored as `YYYY:MM:DD` as your question mentioned?